# HTML+JS+CSS.Как наложить div блок на другой div при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется вот такой шаблончик https://codepen.io/psyapathy/pen/wENPgX

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
        <div id="chat-box">
            <div id="chat-head"> 
            </div>
            <div id="converse"></div>
                <div id="controls">
                <input id="textbox" name="sendtext" class="controls-elements" placeholder="Напишите сообщение" type="text" onkeypress="usl(event)" autofocus></input>
                <button id="send" onclick="buttonOtprav()" class="controls-elements" type="submit">Отправить</button>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div id="sidepanel">
            <div id="sidemenu">
            <div class="buttons">
                <div class="func button">
                </div>
                <div class="dest button">                   
</div>
                <div class="donate button">
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>      
        </div>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Справа на боковой панели есть подобие трёх разноцветных кнопок.
Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии, допустим на первую, справа вылезал аналогичный `sidemenu` блок поверх имеющегося. Допустим с одной кнопкой, чтобы при нажатии ее он закрывался.

Как наложить `div` блок на другой `div` при нажатии на кнопку?

Спасибо заранее

Comment: А где JS код с попыткой что-то сделать?

Comment: наложить можно путем изменения z-index